# Oracle database over ODBC converts non-english characters to question marks

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, unicode, odbc

I am working on retrieving data from an Oracle data source, however I am having issues with non-english characters being replaced with question marks. Some background:

- I am pulling data from an Oracle view whose columns are defined as VARCHAR2
- When accessing said view through Oracle SQL Developer, the results display properly
- I have attempted to update my System.Web.Odbc to the latest version to no avail
- I am aware that the console does not properly display certain Unicode characters, but even viewing the raw data using breakpoints shows said characters replaced with '?'

Here is a runnable example with some specific implementation details removed:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace OdbcTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying ODBC Connection");
            DataTable odbcData = GetData("SELECT NAME as name FROM SYSADM.[ViewName] WHERE TRUNC(sysdate) - to_date(HIRE_DT) BETWEEN 0 AND 20");
            Console.WriteLine(odbcData.Rows.Count.ToString() + "rows extracted.");
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in odbcData.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static DataTable GetData(string SQLStatement)
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection([DSN Details]))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(SQLStatement, connection);
                    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

                    command.CommandTimeout = 600;
                    connection.Open();

                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    connection.Close();
                    return ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have NLS_LANG set?  There are various other SO questions/answers that show how to do that.

Comment: Which ODBC Driver do you use?

Comment: What do you get with `SELECT DUMP(NAME, 1016) FROM ...`? What is the expected output? What is your database character set?

Comment: This is an application that will be deployed to managed servers so a change to NLS_LANG might not be possible. ODBC driver is OraClient 11g; dump result: AL32UTF8, which I believe should support unicode.

Comment: A quick update - I set NLS_LANG locally to match AL32UTF8 to eliminate that as a cause and received the same result upon testing.